# Referencing content from another C#/.NET project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project MyProject with a subfolder MySubFolder which has some content MyContent.txt. The MyContent.txt file's properties are set to "CopyAlways" and "Content".

In another project OtherProject I reference MyProject and try to read the MyContent.txt relative to the OtherProject binary output folder. This fails. I get the MyProject dll but not its contents at compile time.

Short of adding (as a link) the MyContent.txt file in to the OtherProject how do I (best) make the content file of MyProject appear in the OtherProject binary output folder when referencing MyProject.

Comment: Can you have the first project exporting the contents of the file as a public string TextFile{get; set;}?

Comment: Would you consider making the file an embedded resource and reading it stright out of the binary?

Comment: @CuongLe there is no code of interest. The whole thing is a visual studio build problem.